# Delphi 2007, Indy 10. Why can't I typecast a TidBytes buffer?

Tags: delphi, memory, delphi-2007, indy10

Is it not possible to access the data in the memory of a TidBytes buffer with typecasting?  Say I have:

```
type
    TMyRecord = packed record
        Field1 : integer ;
        Field2 : packed array [0..1023] of byte ;
        end ;  

var
  Buffer    : TIdBytes ;
  MyRecord  : TMyRecord ;

begin
  IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadBytes (Buffer, SizeOf (TMyRecord), false) ;

  with TMyRecord (Buffer) do            // compiler snags with "invalid typecast"
  ...
```

OK, so I can use:

```
BytesToRaw (Buffer, MyRecord, SizeOf (TMyRecord)) ;
```

but is there no way of accessing the data directly without the overhead of copying it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it not possible to access the data in the memory of a TidBytes buffer with typecasting?

`TIdBytes` is a *dynamic array* of bytes, so you have to use a type-cast if you want to interpret its raw bytes in any particular format.

> is there no way of accessing the data directly without the overhead of copying it?

A *dynamic array* is implemented by the compiler/RTL as a pointer to a block allocated elsewhere in memory.  So you can use a pointer type-cast to interpret the content of the block, eg:

```
type
  PMyRecord = ^TMyRecord;
  TMyRecord = packed record
    Field1 : integer ;
    Field2 : packed array [0..1023] of byte ;
  end ;  

var
  Buffer: TIdBytes ;
begin
  IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadBytes (Buffer, SizeOf(TMyRecord), false) ;
  with PMyRecord(Buffer)^ do
    ...
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy.  I had tried all the combinations I could think of using `^`, `addr`, and `TMyRecord`, I didn't think to try defining a pointer type.  BTW, should the first word of your answer be *Yes*, rather than *No*?

Comment: You asked if it were possible to access the data without typecasting, and that answer is *No*. But I have re-worded the answer.